# T-SQL Merge - when matched update column and when not matched insert entire row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables;

**DummyTable**

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
a       | b       | c
```

**GoodTable**

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
a       | b       | c
```

I am new to T-SQL and need help doing the following;

Merging data from DummyTable into GoodTable by using conditions

- Conditions: When DummyTable's Column2 matches GoodTable's Column2 then
  update GoodTable's Column3, with DummyTable's Column 3, Else when not matched, Insert that DummyTable's row into GoodTable

Below is my not working attempt

```
MERGE INTO GoodTable AS Target
USING (VALUES (SELECT Column2 FROM DummyTable)) AS source (Column2)
ON Target.Column2 = Source.Column2
WHEN MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
UPDATE (Column2) VALUES (Column2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT INTO GoodTable VALUES DummyTable
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: @Jason i.e. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. But pretty much the whole of the above query is more of a pseudo-code than a real query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you. This is based on your logic above.

```
MERGE INTO GoodTable AS Target
USING DummyTable AS Source
ON Target.Column2 = Source.Column2
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Column3 = source.Column3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Column1,Column2,Column3) --Column names in target table
VALUES (Column1,Column2,Column3); --Column names in source table
```